# Chrome Extension Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm developing an extension. I want to import a function in options.js from commonActions.js but in my console I can see the error **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "ATF",
    "description": "All Time Favourite",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "storage"
    ],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "incognito": "split"
}
```

**commonActions.js**

```
export const search = () => {
    return "Inside search"
}
```

**options.js**

```
import { search } from "./commonActions";
.....
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

File where the function is (test.js)

```
var Tester = function()
{
    // logic
};

export default Tester
```

File you're importing to (main.js)

```
import Tester from './test.js';
Tester();
```

In your html include the file

```
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```